# How to change the attribute value when clicking a button in Vue

Tags: vue.js, attributes, element-ui

I am using Vue Element UI,  how can i change the 'disable' attribute of a inputbox from true to false when clicking the 'edit' button?

```js
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      input1: 'type something here',
    }
  },
  method: {
    editvalue() {
    this.$set('disable',false)
    }

  },
}

var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@1.3.5/lib/theme-default/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@1.3.5/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <el-input placeholder="Please input" v-model="input1" :disabled="true">
  </el-input>
  <el-button size="mini" @click.native="editvalue()">
    Edit</el-button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Added `disable` property to `data`, bound it to `:disabled` and named `methods` properly:

```js
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      input1: 'type something here',
      disable: true,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    editvalue() {
      this.disable = false;
    }

  },
}

var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@1.3.5/lib/theme-default/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@1.3.5/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <el-input placeholder="Please input" v-model="input1" :disabled="disable">
  </el-input>
  <el-button size="mini" @click.native="editvalue()">
    Edit</el-button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `editValue()` method you are doing

```
this.$set('disable',false)
```

This just creates a reactive property named `disable` set to `false` in your `data` option.

But you are not binding the `disabled` attribute of the input to any reactive data

Just initialize a property named `inputDisabled` in your data option, setting it to `true`

```
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      input1: 'type something here',
      inputDisabled: true
    }
  },
  method: {
    editvalue() {
    this.inputDisabled = false;
    }

  },
}

var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

Bind that `inputDisabled` to the disabled attribute as follows

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@1.3.5/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <el-input placeholder="Please input" v-model="input1" :disabled="inputDisabled">
  </el-input>
  <el-button size="mini" @click.native="editvalue()">
    Edit</el-button>
</div>
```

See the `editValue()` method, instead of using `this.$set()` we  just change the value of `inputDisabled` to `false`